# Customizing Vector and Raster menus of QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-customization

As you know QGIS offers the ability to customize all the menus, toolbar, statusbar, using the option **Customization** in the **Settings menu**.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to use that to customize the vector and the raster **menu**. If I un-select some entries, when I reboot QGIS in order to update the view, nothing changes.

For example, I have unchecked certain menu items:

[image]

But nothing changes after restarting, they still appear:

[image]

I also tried to save the configuration file and then load it, but the un-selected entries in the customization menu remain all active.

I'm running QGIS 2.0.1 on a Debian 7.2 machine.

Comment: Got the same problem on Windows 7 and QGIS 2.01 (OSGeo4W)

Comment: Disabling a whole menu entry works for me, but not deselecting single items. WinXP, 32-bit-standalone.

Comment: yeah, I found out that the problem is due to the fact that the function in the Vector menu are provided by ftool while those of the Raster menu by gdal. So it appears that the only thing you can do is deselect the entire menu, but you cannot deselect singles functions

Comment: If you file a bug report/feature request, please post the link to the ticket as an answer.

Comment: @underdark. Hi, I have also reported this problem in a ticket in the qgis-bugtracker. See [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9134)

Comment: Please post that as an answer.

Comment: I didn't receive any answer yet. I if did, I'll post it here. In the meanwhile, the link of the bugtracker is the only thing I can post

Answer (score 2):

I confirm it is/was a bug.
The Vector menu is now customizable and there are work in progress with the Raster menu.

Use QGIS master if you want to see that changes.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a QGIS bug. Followup to the [bug entry](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9134) over on the [normal QGIS bug tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues).

Comment: What I've filled [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9134), is the way to report a bug right?!